# How to get instance of already created TypedActor in java

Tags: akka, typedactor

I use the code like this:

User actor is first created somewhere in the code like this:

```
TypedActor.get(actorSystem).typedActorOf(new TypedProps<UserActor>(IUserActor.class, new Creator<UserActor>() {
        @Override
        public UserActor create() throws Exception {
            return new UserActor(userId);
        }
    }), userId);
```

After that I'm trying to get an instance of it (just like actorFor for UntypedActors):

```
ActorRef userActorRef = actorSystem.actorFor("akka://actors/user/" + userId));
UserActor userActor = TypedActor.get(actorSystem).typedActorOf(new TypedProps<UserActor>(UserActor.class), userActorRef);

// exception is here:
userActor.gotRequest(msg);
```

but once I call a method on userActor I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy5 cannot be cast to com.lutshe.akka.actors.UserActor
    at com.lutshe.akka.AkkaMessagesHandler.process(AkkaMessagesHandler.java:47)
    at com.lutshe.tcp.server.TestMessageHandler.messageReceived(TestMessageHandler.java:31)
    at com.lutshe.tcp.server.TestMessageHandler.messageReceived(TestMessageHandler.java:14)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.java:69)
 ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why is the definition of UserActor omitted from the example?

Comment: UserActor just implements some interface IUserActor:
    public class UserActor implements IUserActor.
I've also added the actor creation code to the question.

Comment: What I'm asking is the actorFor analog for UntypedActors or maybe there's some mistake in the code above...

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: added, but nothing special there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka returns a Proxy of the interface, not the implementation, you should do:

```
 IUserActor userActor = TypedActor.get(actorSystem).typedActorOf(new TypedProps<IUserActor>(UserActor.class), userActorRef);
```